# rdkafka consumer query about partition size

Tags: c++, logging, apache-kafka, producer-consumer, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I don't have access to the set of producers that commits on the partition of interest, but just have control over a bunch of C++ consumers.
Since I'm running benchmarks over a complex program, I'd like to know the spread between the offset my consumers are fetching and the total offset stored in the partition.

e.g., `>> reading message #1234 of 5678 total in partition 0 of topic foo`

I misunderstood the purpose of `RdKafka::Consumer->outq_len()` and `RdKafka::Topic->OFFSET_END`, because they *seem* always equal to `0` and `-1`, respectively.

How can I acquire the `5678` value of my example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to subscribe to `librdkafka`'s statistics to get an updated view of your consumer's lag.
Register an `Event` callback class and regularily call `poll()` on your handle, check for `EVENT_STATS` and then parse the corresponding JSON message and look for `lo_offset`, `hi_offset` and `consumer_lag`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I tried to use statistics data to monitor lag using .NET wrapper for rdkafka (RdKafka) but it returns some wierd lag values. For instance, I configured callback to fire every 30 seconds. In the beginning it returns believeable values but each time they reduce, and it continues until they get down to zero. At the same time I know that nothing consumes from topics and Kafka system tools show me the real values.